# apt-get installs the wrong version of R

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, r

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to install the latest version of R (3.3.2) via `apt-get`, but for some reason, it keeps installing an older version (3.0.2). This is, anytime I type `sudo apt-get install r-base`, it gets me R 3.0.2. This problem has persisted for a while. I was able to procrastinate finding a real solution by downloading the version of R that I wanted and installing it via

```
./configure
make
make install
```

However, now that I want to upgrade my R, it is a good time to figure out why `apt-get` is not working.

I tried updating `apt-get` typing:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
```

But it still insists in installing R 3.0.2.

Comment: That's because the only version of `r-base` available in the default repositories of Trusty is 3.0.2: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/r-base